# Отлов нажатия клавиши без ожидания golang

Tags: golang, клавиатура

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/eiannone/keyboard"
)
func main() {
    char, _, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("You pressed: %q\r\n", char)
}
```

Использую в коде функцию наподобие этой. Проблема в том,что keyboard.GetSingleKey() ждёт нажатия клавиши. Что нужно сделать,чтобы по истечении какого-то времени(например 10мс) программа прерывала ожидание и возвращала nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобные блокирующие операции в таких случаях стоит выносить в отдельные горутины. Например, вот так:

```
 func getKeyTimeout(tm time.Duration) (ch rune, err error) {
    if err = keyboard.Open(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer keyboard.Close()

    var (
        chChan  = make(chan rune, 1)
        errChan = make(chan error, 1)

        timer = time.NewTimer(tm)
    )
    defer timer.Stop()

    go func(chChan chan<- rune, errChan chan<- error) {
        ch, _, err := keyboard.GetSingleKey()
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        chChan <- ch
    }(chChan, errChan)

    select {
    case <-timer.C:
        return 0, errTimeout
    case ch = <-chChan:
    case err = <-errChan:
    }

    return
 }
```

И завершать по таймеру. Вот и всё. Полный пример https://play.golang.org/p/HQ_gUsFW-io

---

В этом примере возвращается `errTimeout`, но он может быть легко перехвачен или заменён на другое значение, в том числе и на nil, если так угодно. Но, думается мне, лучше просто

```
if err != nil && err != errTimeout {
    // обработка ошибки
}
```

Ну или как-то так.